# Postgresql: truncate blocking pg_class and so ALL other SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

During my table updating I have lot of operation Truncate and Insert. But frequently I have problem with bloking table pg_class and becouse of it no one SELECT (even absolutely uninvolved tables) could not work.

When I saw blocking list, I see that this quarry blocking by function where I use truncate.

> SELECT c.oid,c.*,d.description,pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(c.relpartbound, c.oid) as partition_expr,  pg_catalog.pg_get_partkeydef(c.oid) as partition_key , dep.objid, dep.refobjsubid
> FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
> LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d ON d.objoid=c.oid AND d.objsubid=0 AND d.classoid='pg_class'::regclass
> LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_depend dep on dep.refobjid = c."oid" AND dep.deptype = 'i' and dep.refobjsubid <> 0
> WHERE c.relnamespace=$1 AND c.relkind not in ('i','I','c')

I understate, that if I will not use truncate problem was solved, but may be there are any other way to solve it? And why this problem could appear?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this here. `TRUNCATE t` will block reads from table "t" until it commits or rolls back, but I was happily selecting from other tables including pg_class.

Comment: 1) Per here [Truncate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html): *TRUNCATE acquires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on each table it operates on, which blocks all other concurrent operations on the table.*. That lock does not extend to the system tables or other uninvolved tables.  2) More information is needed. **Add as update to question** a) Postgres version.? b) Community version or a fork? c) The actual TRUNCATE query d) What does [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) show?